# How to see the SQL generated by Entity Framework when using an Oracle database?

Tags: .net, oracle, entity-framework, devart, dotconnect

I'm using devArt dotConnect to talk to an oracle 11g database. In another project with SQL Server it was very easy to see the SQL that was generated using the debugging tools from Visual Studio. However this doesn't seem to work when the database is Oracle.

Also, this is a legacy app, so at the moment I'm stuck with EF4.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to an Oracle database so I can't say for sure but I think LINQPad will show you the query regardless of the database